# Searching on two fields like first and last name in ArcGIS Online Web Map App?

Tags: arcgis-online, filter, search

I am creating a web map app of a cemetery. I hope to have a search widget that can search on last name (required) and then first name (optional). I have played around with the search widget, as well as the Filter widget. The filter widget got me closer to my results than the search because you first filter by "user entered last name" *apply* and then you can filter based on first name.

I would also like the results to be highlighted within the application. I know there is an enhanced search widget, which I have applied, but it actually has more functionality than I need and didn't quite give me the correct results.

Comment: Have you tried using WAB search widget and configuring your feature search there? http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-search.htm

Comment: Yes, I'm using web WEB. It doesn't do exactly what I want. I can search last name or first name, but can't first search last name and then within that, search first name. The filter widget seems to provide the best results, but still not exactly what I want. I almost want to code my own widget, but I am not familiar with that and not sure where I would start.

Comment: You could set it up using search in the web map but use a field that contains both first and last name and use the search property contains? http://doc.arcgis.com/en/arcgis-online/create-maps/configure-search-in-apps.htm

Comment: I will give that a try. Seems like that may work and is an easy enough fix. Thanks!

Comment: You can add a field on the feature through the data tab on the item details page and do a field calculate on that in ArcGIS Online if its a hosted feature layer. Or you can do it all through the map viewer as well.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I can't seem to add a field in my feature layer. I keep getting an error. I have created a new field within the map viewer to display the full name. I just wrote an expression that concatenates the first and last name, but since that isn't actually creating data, I can't use that in my search within my web app.

Comment: It is a mapserver, not a featureserver, maybe that's why?

Comment: Yup, sorry for the confusion, I was treating it as a hosted feature layer.

Comment: That's ok. I appreciate your help. I opted for 2 Filters, one that queries based on last name (user entered) and the next one will filter the first name (user entered) based on the last name filter. The problem with this is I can't get it to zoom to the results or highlight, etc. I'm going to meet with the director and see if this satisfies his needs. Otherwise, I may try and look into using the ArcGIS API for Javascript to see if I can add additional functionality to an existing web map app.